# Emacs mu4e maildirs-query problem

Tags: mu4e

When issuing

> M-x mu4e

Selecting context I receive the message :

> error in porcess filter: symbol's function definition is void: mu4e-maildirs-with-query

Mu version 1.6.10

Any idea ?